# Can I use Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR with ASP.NET Core 7 without code changing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr

I want to transform my project from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core 7 so should I use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` or not?

I'm trying to use `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` with an ASP.NET Core project.

I have some problems when I use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` for example:

```
IRequest, Clients.Client().addNewStatusUpdate()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's difficult to understand your question. Please read [ask]

Comment: See this link as to how to create a SignalR application. SignalR library is included in ASP.NET Core 7 Server. So, you should be able to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: What are you trying to achieve could you please explain what issue are getting in `addNewStatusUpdate`? You cannot use `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` with asp.net core because it was aligned with asp.net legracy app. You must need asp.net core signalR or azureSignalR.